# copy_to_user a struct that contains an array (pointer)

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, memory-management

**Disclosure:** I'm fairly new to C. If you could explain any answers verbosely, I would appreciate it.

I am writing a linux kernel module, and in one of the functions I am writing I need to copy a structure to userspace that looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t  someProperty;
    uint32_t  numOfFruits;
    uint32_t  *arrayOfFruits;
} ObjectCapabilities;
```

The API I'm implementing has documentation that describes the `arrayOfFruits` member as "an array of size `numOfFruits` where each element is a FRUIT_TYPE constant." I am confused how to do this, given that the arrayOfFruits is a pointer. When I `copy_to_user` the `ObjectCapabilities` structure, it will only copy the *pointer* `arrayOfFruits` to userspace.

How can userspace continuously access the elements of the array? Here is my attempt:

```
ObjectCapabilities caps;
caps.someProperty = 1024;
caps.numOfFruits  = 3;
uint32_t localArray[] = {
        FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE,
        FRUIT_TYPE_ORANGE,
        FRUIT_TYPE_BANANA
};
caps.arrayOfFruits = localArray;
```

And then for the copy... can I just do this?

```
copy_to_user((void *)destination, &caps, (sizeof(caps) + (sizeof(localArray) / sizeof((localArray)[0]))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user needs to provide enough space for all the data being copied out.  Ideally he'll tell you how much space he provided, and you check that everything fits.

The copied-out data should (in general) not include any pointers, since they're "local" to a different "process" (the kernel can be viewed as a separate process, as it were, and kernel / user interactions involve process-to-process IPC, similar to sending stuff over local or even Internet-connected sockets).

Since the kernel has pretty intimate knowledge of a process, you can skirt these rules somewhat, e.g., you could compute what the user's pointer will be, and copy out a copy of the original data, with the pointer modified appropriately.  But that's kind of wasteful.  Or, you can copy a kernel pointer and just not use it in the user code, but now you're "leaking data" that "bad guys" can sometimes leverage in various ways.  In security-people-speak you've left a wide-open "covert channel".

In the end, then, the "right" way to do this tends to be something like this:

```
struct user_interface_version_of_struct {
    int property;
    int count;
    int data[]; /* of size "count" */
};
```

The user code `malloc`s (or otherwise arranges to have sufficient space) the "user interface version" and makes some system call to the kernel (`read`, `receive`, `rcvmsg`, `ioctl`, whatever, as long as it involves doing a "read"-type operation) and tells the kernel: "here's the memory holding the struct, and here's how big it is" (in bytes, or the maximum `count` value, or whatever: user and kernel simply need to agree on the protocol).  The kernel-side code then verifies the user's values in some appropriate manner, and either does the copy-out however is most convenient, or returns an error.

"Most convenient" is sometimes two separate copy ops, or some `put_user` calls, e.g., if the kernel side has the data structure you showed, you might do:

```
/* let's say ulen is the user supplied length in bytes,
   and uaddr is the user-supplied address */
struct user_interface_version_of_struct *p;

needed = sizeof(*p) + 3 * sizeof(int);
if (needed > ulen)
    return -ENOMEM; /* user did not supply enough space */
p = uaddr;
error = put_user(1024, &p->property);
if (error == 0)
    error = put_user(3, &p->count);
if (error == 0 && copy_to_user(&p->data, localArray, 3 * sizeof(int))
    error = -EFAULT;
```

You may have a situation where you must conform to some not-very-nice interface, though.

---

Edit: if you're adding your own system call (rather than tying in to `read` or `ioctl` for instance), you can separate the header and data, as in [Adam Rosenfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520855/1256452).

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy raw pointers, since a pointer into kernel space is meaningless to userspace (and will segfault if dereferenced).

The typical way of doing something like this is to ask the userspace code to allocate the memory and pass in a pointer to that memory into a system call.  If the program doesn't pass in a large enough buffer, then fail with an error (e.g. `EFAULT`).  If there's no way for the program to know in advance a priori how much memory it will need, then typically you'd return the amount of data needed when passed a `NULL` pointer.

Example usage from userspace:

```
// Fixed-size data
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t  someProperty;
    uint32_t  numOfFruits;
} ObjectCapabilities;

// First query the number of fruits we need
ObjectCapabilities caps;
int r = sys_get_fruit(&caps, NULL, 0);
if (r != 0) { /* Handle error */ }

// Now allocate memory and query the fruit
uint32_t *arrayOfFruits = malloc(caps.numOfFruits * sizeof(uint32_t));
r = sys_get_fruit(&caps, arrayOfFruits, caps.numOfFruits);
if (r != 0) { /* Handle error */ }
```

And here's how the corresponding code would look in kernel space on the other side of the system call:

```
int sys_get_fruit(ObjectCapabilities __user *userCaps, uint32_t __user *userFruit, uint32_t numFruits)
{
    ObjectCapabilities caps;
    caps.someProperty = 1024;
    caps.numOfFruits  = 3;

    // Copy out fixed-size data
    int r = copy_to_user(userCaps, &caps, sizeof(caps));
    if (r != 0)
        return r;

    uint32_t localArray[] = {
        FRUIT_TYPE_APPLE,
        FRUIT_TYPE_ORANGE,
        FRUIT_TYPE_BANANA
    };

    // Attempt to copy variable-sized data.  Check the size first.
    if (numFruits * sizeof(uint32_t) < sizeof(localArray))
        return -EFAULT;
    return copy_to_user(userFruit, localArray, sizeof(localArray));
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(localArray)` should be `(sizeof(localArray) / sizeof((localArray)[0]))` right?

Comment: No, the compare uses bytes on both sides (`numFruits * sizeof...` vs `sizeof`) and the `copy_to_user` needs the number of bytes to copy, not the number of items.

Answer (score 2):

With `copy_to_user` you would do two copy to users.

```
//copy the struct
copy_to_user((void *)destination, &caps, sizeof(caps));
//copy the array.
copy_to_user((void *)destination->array, localArray, sizeof(localArray);
```

Comment: So, are you saying that I cannot declare variables locally in a function and then "copy_to_user" them? I **have** to malloc them before the copy? I was hoping that the copy process made it so that it didn't matter that at the end of the function all that memory was blown away.

Comment: @unexpected62   I am not 100% sure. Let me look into this

Comment: No problem. Just curious, why are two copy_to_users necessary? I thought that an array was just the pointer to the first element in the array. I ask, because I am unable to do the `destination->array` part.

Comment: @unexpected62 you are right, you can do the stack based like you had, kmalloc isn't necessary. The two copies are necessary with a pointer like that. Since copy_to_user will essentially do a kernel memcpy to userspace it will only copy contiguous data. So it can't see that there is a pointer and start copying the array as well. There will need to be another copy.

Comment: First off, thanks a lot for the help. I understand what you're saying conceptually, but what I'm saying is how can I do `destination->array` if the `destination` is of type `unsigned long`. I can't access a field within it. What i've done is: `copy_to_user(((ObjectCapabilities*)destination)->array`. That seems to work actually.

Comment: @unexpected62, I know what you're saying, I am actively looking into this. I can't seem to find much on google, regarding copying structs with pointers. I know a way around this, but I don't like it as it's hacky and architecture dependent. Since we know destination is a pointer to the start of the struct (`someProperty`), which is contiguous memory, we can do some pointer arithmetic to get us to the location of the array pointer. The problem is, different architectures align on different offsets, so padding is different, so a simple `(char*)destination + (2*sizeof(uint32_t))` may not work.

Comment: Excellent. I see what you are saying. My solution I mentioned in my above comment is compiling fine now, so I think I'm ok, and I avoid the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @unexpected62 oh I didnt read that fully, that should work as the hack I just mentioned is exactly what the compiler would do but it knows about the architecture

Comment: If you edit your answer to remove the kmalloc, etc, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot @Scotty Bauer